# .htaccess Redirect to script in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I need to have a .htaccess rewrite rule redirect to a script in the root of a subdirectory, but only for any files/directories in that sub directory...

```
/
/subdir/
   /index.php
   /somedir/
   /anotherdir/
```

For the structure above, I want anyone browsing to /subdir to go to /subdir/index.php, and anyone going to /subdir/somedir/ to /subdir/index.php etc...

If however, they go to the root directory. they should stay there... I've tried putting an .htaccess file in /subdir with a bunch of attempts at rewrite rules but so far none work.

**update:** I don't mean just the */somedir/* needs to redirect ot index.php, but any subdirectory of */subdir/* needs to be redirect... Scripts too, but obviously not */subdir/index.php*

Sorry I wasn't clear before.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, the only actual redirection that needs to happen is if someone goes to /subdir/somedir (redirect them back to the index.php

If that's the case, this should work, put in /.htaccess:

```
redirect /subdir/somedir/ /subdir/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an internal redirect, try this [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/somedir/index\.php
RewriteRule ^subdir/somedir/ subdir/index.php [L]
```

For an external redirect, just add the `R` flag (with an optional redirect status code: `R=`*`xxx`*; default: 302):

```
RewriteRule … [L,R=xxx]
```