# .htaccess URL Rewrite to Subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What is the best method to rewrite anything below "/some/subdir" to "/some/subdir/projects" like from this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/some/subidr/test/
```

... to this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/some/subdir/projects/test/
```

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521019/htaccess-redirect-to-script-in-subdirectory) posted, but the solution didn't seem to work in my case. My current attempt so far (which doesn't seem to work):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/projects/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projects/$1 [L]
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention the .htaccess file would have to be sitting within /some/subdir as I don't have write access to the server's web root.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the solution I finally got to work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some/subdir/projects/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /some/subdir/projects/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Looks like this redirects, not rewrites

Answer (score 7):

Try this rule in your .htaccess configuration file in the document root of your server:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^some/subdir/projects(/|$) some/subdir/projects%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

---

As you want to use this rule in your `/some/subdir/` directory, change the rule as follows:

```
RewriteRule !^projects(/|$) projects%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

And if you want to redirect any requests of `/some/subdir/projects/`*`foobar`* to `/some/subdir/`*`foobar`*, put this rule above the previous mentioned:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /some/subdir/projects[/?\s]
RewriteRule ^some/subdir/projects/?([^/].+)?$ /some/subdir/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: How might I do this with an .htaccess file inside "/some/subdir" since I don't have write access to the server's web root?

Comment: Remove the `some/subdir/` from both the pattern and substitute. The rest should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(/some/subdir)/(.*)$ $1/projects/$2
```

This will redirect `/some/subdir/<anything>` to `/some/subdir/projects/<anything>`.

Note that the leading `/` is actually required to match the beginning of the URL, *unless* you have `RewriteBase /` set somewhere.

Comment: The leading slash is only required when used in the server or virtual host configuration. In a .htaccess config file the per-directory prefix if removed before tested and later appended to the substition.

Comment: I was having massive headache with / missing from the subfolder, - not much info around on this problem, but if you just want to redirect to subfolder the person actually came from, do the following -      RewriteRule /?([^/].+)?$ http://examplen.com/$1 [R=301,L]