# Using .htaccess to rewrite the url in a sub directory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect a url pattern like

```
http://abcd.com/some/sub/directory/var1
```

to

```
http://abcd.com/some/sub/directory/?search=var1
```

I've read other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864507/htaccess-url-rewrite-to-subdirectory). But none of them solved my problem.
I don't have write access to root directory. So I've placed this .htaccess file in "/some/sub/directory/"

Edit : Here is my current htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ product/?search=$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the htaccess file to take effect, the server admin must have the appropriate `AllowOverride` setting in their Apache configuration.  If your htaccess does nothing, this setting is probably disabled.  Otherwise, use mod_rewrite normally.

Comment: How can I check whether it is enabled or disabled by the admin?

Comment: If you put utter garbage in it and your page still displays peachily, it's disabled.