# Rewrite url from /forum/page/ to /page/ (actual files are located within /forum/)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have forum files located within a folder directory.  Right now my urls look like this

```
http://www.example.com/forum/fx/pagename/
```

However I am wondering if I can use mod rewrite to rewrite my urls in the following format while keeping the forum files within the forum folder:

```
http://www.example.com/fx/pagename/
```

where x equals a number

Comment: Are there any mod-rewrites already?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess URL Rewrite to Subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864507/htaccess-url-rewrite-to-subdirectory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have this rule in `DocumentRoot` (a level above forum) .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!forum/).+)$ /forum/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^f([0-9]+)/([^/]+) /forum/f$1/$2 [L]
```