# Rewrite URLs using .htaccess to a subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

my problem is that I moved my entire website to a subfolder of the public-html one. Tried to rewrite the URLS to automatically add the subfolder via the .htaccess but didn't succeed 
this is the code :

```
ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized"
ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php index.cgi index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ anb/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess URL Rewrite to Subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864507/htaccess-url-rewrite-to-subdirectory)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by deleting the line

```
RewriteBase /
```

Apparently the RewriteBase doesn't work well when the .htaccess is placed in the root directory A.K.A [public_html]